# Entity framework codefirst adding table

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How to add existing table  to existing codefirst entity framework project.

Can you please suggest

Comment: can you explain your question in bit details

Comment: this can help you http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-from-existing-database.aspx